# Python function fails to initialize argument value

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have a function that iterates over a  many levels nested dictionary (arg1) collecting data over each iteration, something like this:

```
def dummy(arg1, found=[], index=0):
    found.append('xyz')

    for d in arg1:
        dummy(arg1[d], found, index+1)

    return found
```

My functions work as it's supposte to, the problem is that when I call the function a second time, the found argument keeps the value from the previous function call, i.e. the return value from the second call includes the return values from the previous call. I had to add something like

```
if index == 0:
   found=list() # restart value
```

to the beginning of the function to initialize the value of the found argument. Any idea why this happens? is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a bug; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

To avoid this, you should do:

```
def dummy(arg1, found=None, index=0):
    if found is None:
        found = []
    ...
```

or better yet (see [here](https://treyhunner.com/2019/03/unique-and-sentinel-values-in-python/)):

```
sentinel = object()
def dummy(arg1, found=sentinel, index=0):
    if found is sentinel:
        found = []
    ...
```